# Navigate to plain HTML page from react page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have my single page react application and I am trying to implement a button that when clicked it loads a whole different page that has it's own HTML, JS, and CSS. I thought I had the logic down, but when I click the button it just loads my react app again and resets all the states so it never leaves.

It actually just re-renders it really small for some reason.

It looks like this: 
[image: MY REACT PAGE]

Here's the general logic I'm using.

In my state I have a load page state initially set to false. `loadPage: false`

Then on my page I have a button that when clicked calls this function

```
loadPage() {
    this.setState({
        loadPage: true
    });
}
```

Finally in my render function I have an if to load the external page if the state says so

```
render() {
        if(this.state.loadPage){
            return (
                <iframe id="pageDiv" src='path to html file'/>
            )
        }
```

The problem I'm running into seems to be that when I click the button and change the state the app re-renderes but resets the existing state at the same time.

I just want to have a button that when clicked COMPLETELY navigates away from my react page and loads this separate html page. They are in the same project so it's not loading a URL its loading an HTML file.

Comment: do you want to render `html` page? when click on one of a button ? Do you want to render that page in react application or in a different tab

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap  inside a  like this:

```
 render() {
     if(this.state.loadPage){
         return (
    <a href=" path to html file">
    <iframe id="pageDiv"/>
    </a>
         )
     }
```

Or you can also use react-r

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

 render() {
     if(this.state.loadPage){
         return (
    <Link to=" path to html file">
    <iframe id="pageDiv"/>
    </Link>
         )
     }
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load the new page in the iframe, that's why it's happening this way. If you want to navigate to the new page, use

`window.location = "/anotherpage";` -- for another page in same domain

`window.location = "http://newpage_url.com";` -- for page in some other domain